# How to install precompiled binaries in linux

Tags: linux, sqlite, library

I am trying to install a **pre-compiled** sqlite version 3 (sqlite3) binary in linux. I created a directory `/home/username/src` and I placed the zip file in the directory then unzipped the file. What I was left with was sqlite3. When I try to use it I get an error saying sqlite3 is not installed. I have tried the commands:

```
install sqlite3
make install
```

Comment: Did you also install the library?

Answer (score 2):

You should not download sqlite yourself but install it from the repositories of your distributions using the package manager. On Debian/Ubuntu you would do:

```
 sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev
```

Depending on what programming language you are using, you should also install the proper bindings. Those are often available as packages as well.

Comment: Would you be so kind to read my answer before complaining? I explicitly mention that this is for debian/ubuntu. If the OP needs instructions for a different distribution, he can say so and I will amend my answer.

Comment: @kim-stebel: you are completely right. sorry.

Comment: Also, the OP probably only needs `sqlite3`.  Of course, depending on what he needs it for, he may only need `libsqlite3-0`, or he may only need `libsqlite3-dev`.

Comment: well, this question started out on SO, so I assumed he needs -dev too. Anyway, a few extra packages never hurt anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it like:

```
cd /home/username/src
./sqlite3
```

Note the leading "./" there. You can also move it into /usr/local/bin, which is probably in your $PATH, verify with:

```
echo $PATH
```

and then you can run it from anywhere like:

```
sqlite3
```